# Possible to use PHP GD's imagecreatefromgif() and imagettftext() together?

Tags: php, gd

Basically I am looking for a way to write dynamic text on top of a GIF [preferably via PHP GD.] But I can't seem to get these two functions to play nice.

For reference: [imagecreatefromgif](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php) & [imagettftext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

```
function load_gif($imgname)
{
    $im = @imagecreatefromgif($imgname);

    if(!$im)
    {
        $im = imagecreatetruecolor(150,30);
        $bgc = imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);
        $tc = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0);

        imagefilledrectangle($im,0,0,150,30,$bgc);

        imagestring($im,1,5,5,'Error loading ' . $imgname,$tc);
    }

    return $im;
}

if ($_GET['color'] == 'red')
{
    header('Content-Type:image/gif');

    //$img = imagecreatetruecolor(51,32); // THIS IS NEEDED FOR TEXT TO SHOW
    $img = load_gif('map-bubble-' . $_GET['color'] . '.gif');

    $black = imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,0);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($img,255,255,255);

    imagefilledrectangle($img,0,0,51,32,$black);
    imagettftext($img,14,0,0,0,$white,'../arial.ttf','test');

    imagegif($img);

    imagedestroy($img);
}
```

Comment: Let's see your code.  Tell us what error messages you are getting.

Comment: what do you mean by "I can't seem to get these two functions to play nice"?

Comment: If you look at my code sample I just added, when I define $img using imagecreatetruecolor() I can use the text but it is a solid background color, but what I use imagecreatefromgif() if won't allow text.  Meaning it is one or the other hence not playing nice

Answer (score 2):

What if you create a new truecolour image, import the gif into that, add the text, then output the result again as a gif - you may have more luck that way.

Comment: Can you go more into depth on steps 1 & 2, especally on how exactly to import a GIF into a truecolor image.

Comment: I guess I should specify: I think this is WHAT I need to do, the question is HOW

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the imagecreatefromgif into a variable, run imagettftext, then output the image using an content-type header. Take a look at the arguments, and fill in the $image argument with the outptu from imagecreatefromgif.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
if ($_GET['color'] == 'red' && strlen($_GET['number']) > 0 && is_numeric($_GET['number']))
{
    $image = imagecreatefromgif('map-bubble-' . $_GET['color'] . '.gif');

    $image_width = imagesx($image);

    $text_size = @imagettfbbox(10,0,'../arial.ttf','$' . $_GET['number']);
    $text_width = abs($text_size[2]-$text_size[0]);

    imagettftext($image,10,0,($image_width / 2) - ($text_width / 2),17,imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255),'../arial.ttf','$' . $_GET['number']);

    header('Content-type:image/gif');
    imagegif($image);

    imagedestroy($image);
}
```